# What does "I was had" mean?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

> Maybe he would help me with Deborah's pablum, take turns pushing the wheelchair. It's good to have someone.
>
> That reminded me that I had someone -- or perhaps I was had. In any case, Rita would want to know I would be late, [...]

This is the first time I see a sentence like this. What tense is that *I was had* ?

EDIT: Wider context added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without a little more context I can't be sure which of two interpretations to put on it: one positive, one negative, both slang (and not-quite-correct grammar.)

Positive: I had someone, and s/he had me; I *was had*.  To **have** someone, in an indefinite sentence like this, means to *be involved romantically with* someone.  ["I once had a girl - or should I say, she once had me?"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkcRZSdc8us)  ("Was had" is not only grammatically nonstandard, but extremely unusual.)

Negative: I had had someone - or had I been had?  To **[be had](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/be+had)** is to get fooled or cheated; in this interpretation the writer knows that s/he has just engaged in a battle of wits, and either won or lost... but isn't sure which.

Edit: with a bit more context (the passage is from a [Dexter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_Morgan) novel, [TWELVE](http://www.scribd.com/doc/57683613/14/TWELVE)), the meaning becomes clearer.

Deborah has just been stabbed, and will perhaps be brain-damaged; Dexter has called an occasional boyfriend of hers.  "Maybe he (the boyfriend) would help me with Deborah...  It's good to have someone."  *It's good to have someone **to take care of you.***

"That reminded me that I had someone" - Dexter has a <strike>girlfriend</strike> wife, Rita, to take care of him - "or perhaps I was had."  Maybe it's the other way around - maybe Rita has Dexter to take care of *her*.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't heard "to be had" in the first sense you mention (but then again I'm not a native speaker). I'd have assumed the second, but the first probably makes more sense here.

Comment: I think the first sense, if phrased this way, is highly unusual. The second sense is certainly the more likely meaning.

Comment: In this case, it could even be a mixture of the two: "I thought I had someone (a significant other) -- or maybe I was had (the relationship is/was a sham)." It really depends on the context.

Comment: @Urbycoz, it is unusual only in form "I was had", in both OPs full example and example that MT_Head gives, the meaning of having someone is quite likely (first part of sentence uses the word in one way, the second part uses it in different)

Comment: I've added a little more context, is it easier for you to decide now? By the way, it's from a normal book, I'd say there's pretty good chance it's grammatically correct or at least intentional to write like that but who knows, nobody's perfect.

Comment: MT_Head: are you confident about it? I ask because Dexter is written there as emotionless serial killer who uses Rita's marriage only as disguise (I'm aware of the fact you couldn't know that) so maybe there's a bit of truth on JoseK's explanation?

Comment: @Miro - I think @JoseK was under the impression (as I was at first) that the narrator was a woman; his interpretation made sense from that perspective, but not from Dexter's.  I've not read any of the books, and I never could get into the TV show, but I've seen/read enough to know who/what Dexter is (in a very superficial way, I mean - I don't mean that I have a deep insight into his soul!).

Comment: MT_Head: OK, we've got the meaning settled then. What about the actual word usage, why not "she had me", as you suggest? Is it really possible it's grammatically incorrect even in the book, esp. in so popular one?

Comment: @Miro - Sadly, being a bestselling author does not guarantee good grammar; on the other hand, it might have been intentional.  I've been thinking about this phrase, off and on, for the last hour; it may just be that I'm tired and sleepy, but I can't even tell you exactly why it's ungrammatical.  It just _feels_ wrong... which might be exactly the effect the author had in mind.

Comment: But that's the whole point. It _sounds_ incorrect. It is a play on the word _had_ in two ways: Do I have her, or am I had, or have I been had? I've been had (cheated) and had (owned).

Comment: @Tragicomic - that's what I thought too, until I read a bit more of the novel.