# Usage of [to be] + had

Tags: grammar, word-usage

While discussing [What does "I was had" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/31355/4035) I've found there are some not so common usages of *had* in English like:

> I have/had been had

(meaning "to get fooled")

but further Google search exposed even constructions like

> I am been had

or even

> I am had

and of course

> I was had

from the question above. Are all of those grammatically correct? Can you give me some usage examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am been had

This is a very odd construction. Of the four hits that Google offers two are obvious solecisms and [one is a double](http://www.archive.org/stream/cu31924026448401/cu31924026448401_djvu.txt) that uses it as a literal translation from another language.

> I am had

This is also awkward. Possibly it had a use once, but today it would be at least archaic if not downright wrong.

> I was had.

Along with "I've been had," this is acceptable grammatically and means the speaker was swindled or deceived by someone.