# Meaning of "Almost every kinky kind was being had and enjoyed."

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

I saw this sentence in [NYT OP](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/07/03/magazine/infidelity-will-keep-us-together.html?_r=1&partner=rss&emc=rss&pagewanted=print):

> "Almost every kinky kind **was being had** and enjoyed."

What does the part in bold mean? What grammar rules pertain to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does “I was had” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31355/what-does-i-was-had-mean)

Comment: @Philoto: this is a different usage of "had".

Comment: @Rhodri Are you sure? I thought in MT_Head's answer to that question all possible ways of using "to be had" had been explained.

Comment: @Philoto: Ah.  Sorry, you are quite right, I made a mistaken assumption based on the question title.  On the other hand I think the unusual tense used here merits a question of its own, so I'm not going to vote to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bolded verb phrase is a *passive past progressive*, which is not a tense that you see every day. If we reverse the passive and restore some elided words we get the following:

> [People] were having almost every kinky kind [of sex] and enjoying it.

Note that deploying the passive in this way is a kind of play on words. The idiom *to have sex* normally is not cast in the passive, because *sex* is not really a normal object of the verb *have*, but is rather an integral part of the idiomatic expression *have sex*. The statement *Sex was had* is unusual and surprising, though still intelligible. In the linked article, Savage uses this unusual passive construction in order to put the focus of the sentence of *kinky kind [of sex]* and create a parallelism between *had* and *enjoyed*.

Answer (score 2):

More context from your link reveals what's missing:

> Not that heeding our desires always simplifies matters. One recent writer to Savage Love thought he would enjoy seeing his wife fool around with another man, and initially did: “Almost every kinky kind was being had and enjoyed.” But when his wife had vaginal intercourse with the other man, something happened.

What's missing is "sex"; the line omits that because it's supposed to be understood from context as meaning:

> "Almost every kinky kind [of sex] was being had and enjoyed."

The "was being had" means the couple mentioned had been *having* sex.